# Open modal popup on another modal popup

Tags: asp.net, html, jscript

I want to show a modal on another modal while its still visible.
I am unable to understand what should I do. I tried z-index but its not working for me.
Any kind of guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

> - Data-dismiss: used for closing modal.
> - Data-toggle:used for popup modal.

```
<a data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href="#ModalId">Click</a>
```

**OR**
you can use onclicke method.

```
<a id="ID" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" onclick="functionShowModal()">Click</a>
```

Jscript

```
   functionShowModal()
{
$("#ID").load("#ModalId");
}
```

You have to define z-index for them accordingly as well. You will find more about z-index [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index)

Comment: I want to open 1st modal(Parent) and at the same time on button click I want to popup 2nd modal while 1st modal is visible.

Comment: As I mentioned above Data-dismiss, leave it empty if you dont want to close parent modal.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out this
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples

```html
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="gridSystemModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-3 .col-md-offset-3</div>
          <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-4">.col-md-2 .col-md-offset-4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">.col-md-6 .col-md-offset-3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-9">
            Level 1: .col-sm-9
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                Level 2: .col-xs-8 .col-sm-6
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-6">
                Level 2: .col-xs-4 .col-sm-6
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

$(#id_name).modal("toggle") <-- popup
$(#id_name).modal("hide") turn off